# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable on list indexing

Tags: python

Why does this code work throw error "`if list[(userlstlen-1)] < list[(userlstlen-2)]: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`"

I'm not indexing or calling any type/ object here.

```
def find_linear_quadratic(userlst, userlstlen):
    while userlstlen != 0:
        print("iteration: \n", userlstlen)
        # Start body here
        if list[(userlstlen-1)] < list[(userlstlen-2)]:
            A = list[(userlstlen-1)]
            list[(userlstlen-1)] = list[(userlstlen-2)]
            list[(userlstlen-1)] = A
            userlstlen -= 1
    return userlst

def main():
    list = [3,2,1]
    lstlen = list.__len__()

    find_linear_quadratic(list, lstlen)

main()
```

Comment: _"I'm not indexing or calling any type/ object here."_ What do you mean? You're using square brackets on an object, e.g. indexing, and you're doing it on `list`, which is a type.

Comment: Your list may be named `list` *outside* the function (which is a bad idea, as you're shadowing the built-in type), but *inside* the function it takes the parameter name `userlst`. Also you should rarely call `__magic_methods__` directly - `thing.__len__()` should be `len(thing)`.

Comment: In `main()` you redefine the built-in `list` type to be a (local) variable, so using it works there. However that's not the case in `find_linear_quadratic()` where it's using the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the problem:

[List](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is the valid python data type, while you shadow the type in main function:

```
def main():
    list = [3,2,1]
    lstlen = list.__len__()

    find_linear_quadratic(list, lstlen)
```

it's still local for main only and not visible for `find_linear_quadratic` function, therefore when you are trying to address it inside the `find_linear_quadratic`, e.g.:

```
def find_linear_quadratic(userlst, userlstlen):
    while userlstlen != 0:
        print("iteration: \n", userlstlen)
        # Start body here
        if list[(userlstlen-1)] < list[(userlstlen-2)]:
            A = list[(userlstlen-1)]
            list[(userlstlen-1)] = list[(userlstlen-2)]
            list[(userlstlen-1)] = A
            userlstlen -= 1
    return userlst
```

The `list[(userlstlen-1)] < list[(userlstlen-2)]`refers to the python data type instead of the variable you have defined in main, therefore leading to the error message:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Basically it's bad habit to call your variable with names of inner data types or packages, since this usually ends up with such errors and leads to confusion.